# Python Print Unsolved References

Tags: python, printing, reference

I am an absolute beginner in python and I am trying to understand why the last line does not work. PyCharm states that the "n" is an unsolved reference, I have made sure that the function returns the string input. Is it a problem with the line itself or with the function?

```
def askforname():
    n = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    return n


def printchoice():
    print("You are starving and go down to the kitchen.")
    print("You are now confronted with an eon defining choice, spaghetti or lasagna")


def hello(n):
    print("Hello " + n + "!")


def choiceone():
    choicelasagna = str(input("Type \"Lasagna\" to pick lasagna and type \"Spaghetti\" to pick spaghetti: "))
    return choicelasagna


def kalle():
   ch = choiceone()
   if ch == "Lasagna" or "lasagna":
      print("You cooked some warm lasagna and enjoyed it")
else:
    print("You cooked some spaghetti and enjoyed it")


def main():
    n = askforname()
    hello(n)
    printchoice()
    kalle()


def goodbye(n):
    print("Goodbye" + n)


def request():
    print("")


main()
goodbye(n)
```

Comment: n is not defined hence python doesnt know what it is, add an `n = "David"` before the function call and check what happen

Comment: I want "n" to be defined by a string input

Comment: `main() ; goodbye(n)` Where is `n` defined?

Comment: You are defining `n` in `main`, but that `n` is not available to `goodbye` since it is not global.

Comment: n is defined inside main so it will stay in stack memory for the time the main executes after that it is not defined globally . read about "scope of variables"

Comment: Also, stop converting the input to string. Anything you enter in input is string automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is only defined in function `main`.  In order to access `n` outside of `main`, you need to return it from `main`

```
def main():
    n = askforname()
    hello(n)
    printchoice()
    kalle()
    return n
```

and capture the returned value :

```
n = main()
```

You can then access `n` for whatever you want:

```
print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are passing a variable `n` to the `goodbye(n)` function without first defining `n`. Since the name `n` does not point to any value, it is an unsolved reference.

Defining `n` in `main()` does not make it accessible to functions outside `main()`. Such a rule is called a **scope rule**. The scope of a variable is the region of the code where it can be accessed freely, including the region where it is defined.

In this case, the scope of `n` is limited to the `main()` function. This means that `n` is unavailable to functions outside `main()`; thus `n` is undefined and you cannot pass its (nonexistent) value to another function.

You may define `n` *outside* `main()` in order to make it accessible to other functions:

```
...

def main():
    hello(n)  # here n references a global variable
    printchoice()
    kalle()

...

# n is defined globally outside main()
n = askforname()
main()
goodbye(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Is That goodbye(n) Does Not Know What 'n' Is, As 'n' Is A Local Variable Of main() function And Its Scope Is Limited To Main. Other Functions Would Not Recognize This Variable As Its Scope Is Not Global. It Is A Local Variable Of main().
To Access 'n' In Other Functions You Can Declare It Globally Right Before You Call The main() function, Separate From Other Functions.

```
#To Change Global Variable In Funtions Add Global Before The Variable 
def askforname():
    global n = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    return n
```